# Ghost input box appears when focused

Tags: html, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap used. HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<input class="list-group-item form-control text-right" 
       name="s" id="sidebar-primary" type="search" 
       placeholder="Search? " autocomplete="off" 
       autofocus spellcheck="false">
```

Everything is fine except when I open it with MS IE 10. (MS IE 8 & 9 also cannot display it well, but not this problem.)

[image: Input box displayed in MSIE 10]

There is a *ghost input box*(don't know how to describe it alternatively). It only appears when the input box is focused.
How to remove that?

Answer (score 0):

If you really just wanna remove it and not figure out where it came from:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sidebar-primary').remove();
});
```

Comment: Not to remove the input box! Only remove the ghost/shadow one.

Comment: lol well without a link to see it myself or the code pasted I really don't know what that means :(